# C#, Datagridview, SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, datetimepicker

I have a SQL Server database with a table called `Purchase`. In my Windows Form, I have 2 `DataGridview` (DataGridView1, DataGridView2). `DataGridView1` is bound to the `Purchase` table and it shows all of the purchases including a column `PurchaseDateTime`.

I have a `dateTimePicker1` on my form.

I want to show the specific date which is chosen by the user in the `dateTimePicer1` and filter my `dataGridView1` and show the filtered data in `dataGridView2`.

I would appreciate if anyone help me in this case.

Comment: check faq first that how to ask question.

Comment: This is a bad example of title. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use Following Code:**

```
try
{
  con.open(); 
  cmd=new SqlCommand("select * from purchaseTable where convert(nvarchar(11),dateCol)=convert(datetime,@dtpValue)",conn);
  cmd.parameters.AddWithValue("@dtpValue",dtpDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
  SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  adapter.Fill(dataset);
  gv.DataSource=ds.Tables[0];
  con.close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
finally
{
  con.close();
}
```

Write this code on date change event.

Hope its helpful.

Comment: * con = SQL server connection object
* dtpDate = DateTimePicker
* gv = DataGridView